# GIS data for world map for geocoding usage

Tags: gis, geocoding, geocode, openmaptiles, world-map

Hi I looking for another alternative to Open Street Map (OSM) to download world map gis data for geocoding usage in my application.

The reason why I am not looking into OSM for geocoding is because not all OSM data are accurate and OSM data contains many redundant fields (the fields I only need are lat, lon and place names).

Would love to know of other such providers..

Comment: You can extract just the needed columns from an OSM planet pbf file into a CSV file using a tool like osmosis.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to stackoverflow.

[Natural earth data](https://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/) site has some free GIS data.

I'm not sure what you exactly need but in this site you can find a lot of layers include rasters, physical, and cultural in 3 different scales (1:10M, 1:50M and 1:110M).

In most accurate scale(1:10 million) you can find countries, roads, populated places(cities) and a lot more data that can help you.
These layers contain a lot of field that could be helpful for demos or training purposes.

Hope this helps.